# Mithril - Rerender dynamic content

Tags: javascript, request, deferred, mithril.js

I am trying to re render my DOM elemnets after my deferred object returns with data. I debug this on the console and it appears that my elements are getting created, however it never shows up to the page. If I add static content it works as intended.

```
        m('div', {class: 'table-responsive'}, [
            m('table', {class: 'table'}, [
                m("thead", [
                    m('tr', [
                        m('th', '#'),
                        m('th', 'Groups'),
                    ])
                ]),
                m('tbody', findGroupsDeferred.promise.then(function(data){ // findGroupsDeferred returns when the promise is complete with my data.
                    data.group.map(function(group) {
                        return m("tr", [
                            m("td", [
                                m("input[type=checkbox] checked", {
                                    value: group,
                                    onclick: function (event) {
                                        if (event.target.checked) {
                                            ctrl.addGroup(ctrl.groups(event.target.value))
                                        } else {
                                            ctrl.removeGroup(ctrl.groups(event.target.value))
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                            ]),
                            m("td", group),
                        ])
                    });
                }))
            ])
        ]),
```

Answer (score 2):

Roamer-1888 Is quite right. This can't be done in the view. You have a few options to achieve this:

First on is to wait for the result in the controller:

```
controller: function() {
  scope = {
    groups: []
  }
  findGroupsDeferred.promise.then(function(data) {
    scope.groups = data.group;
  }
  return scope;
},
view: function(scope) {
  return scope.groups.map(function(group) {
    return group.name // or what ever you want to do here
  }
}
```

Another option is to create a [component](https://lhorie.github.io/mithril/components.html) for this which pretty much results in the same code accept the it's encapsulated. Third option is to use [`m.prop`](https://lhorie.github.io/mithril/mithril.prop.html) together with mithrils defered for this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know mithril but would guess that a promise can't be used in quite that way.

From first principles of promises, it would make more sense to wrap the entire `m()` expression with `promise.then(...)`. In other words, build the *entire* table after `findGroupsDeferred.promise` resolves, rather than trying to target an inner portion of the table.

```
findGroupsDeferred.promise.then(function(data) { // findGroupsDeferred returns when the promise is complete with my data.
    m('div', {class: 'table-responsive'}, [
        m('table', {class: 'table'}, [
            m("thead", [
                m('tr', [
                    m('th', '#'),
                    m('th', 'Groups'),
                ])
            ]),
            m('tbody', data.group.map(function(group) {
                return m("tr", [
                    m("td", [
                        m("input[type=checkbox] checked", {
                            value: group,
                            onclick: function (event) {
                                if (event.target.checked) {
                                    ctrl.addGroup(ctrl.groups(event.target.value));
                                } else {
                                    ctrl.removeGroup(ctrl.groups(event.target.value));
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    ]),
                    m("td", group),
                ]);
            }))
        ])
    ]),
});
```

Alternatively mithril has a mechanism for [rendering before web service requests finish](https://lhorie.github.io/mithril/mithril.request.html#rendering-before-web-service-requests-finish), which may be relevant here.